# set flash not working in zxing scanner library

Tags: zxing

can u show the full code for button on click method for toggle turn on/off flash when scan? I have try this, but not working, Im using

```
val mScannerView = object : ZXingScannerView(this) {
            override fun createViewFinderView(context: Context?): IViewFinder {
                return CustomViewFinderView(context!!)
            }
        }

btn.setOnclickListener{

  if(flashStatus){

     mScannerView.setFlash(true)

  }else{

    mScannerView.setFlash(false)
}
```

thanks